# (A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.) in visual studio when deploying to device

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, profile, provisioning

After upgrading visual studio to 2022 17.0.6
I am unable to deploy to a device.

Things I have tried:

1. Created New Certificate in developer.apple
2. Created new Development Provisioning Profile with Physical Device and Downloaded locally. (Did this at least 20 times)
3. Deleted Bin and Obj Directories in iOS Project Directory.
4. Added a different Device and tried that.
5. In Visual Studio, set the Certificate and Provisioning Profile Explicitly.

If anyone has had this issue and knows any additional areas i could try that would be so helpful.
Thank you community in advance!

--Visual Studio: 17.0.6
--OP: Monterey 12.4
--XCode: 13.4.1

side note:
Everything used to work fine, but this all went haywire after upgrading the MAC, XCode and Visual Studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831593/cant-deploy-xamarin-app-to-ios-device-provisioning-profile-missing-private-ke

Comment: Did you run Xcode, and use it to download the profile *to the device*?